# Some pages missing : jupyter notebook convert to pdf

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, pdf-generation

I am tying to convert this [notebook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqx12cjyuu02s59/control-grape-cnot.ipynb?dl=0) into a pdf. The resulting [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bh85pu2b6hfrbr8/control-grape-cnot.pdf?dl=0) only has the first page of the notebook. 
Why does this happen ? 
Edit1:
Click on File > Download as > PDF via Latex
[way to convert notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHxni.png)

Comment: How do you convert? Is your issue related to programming?

Comment: Please look at my edit. hopefully it answers your question.